# Rails ActiveRecord query pluck select sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sum

I have a complicated query that calculates the sum of the weight of an object's relational trait (For PosgreSQL)

```
Object.joins(:object_traits).where(object_trait: {name: [list_of_names]}).select("sum(object_traits.weight) as sum_weight, #{other direct object traits}").group("#{other direct object traits}").order('weight_sum')
```

Ideally I would like to pluck the sum of the weights for each Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the argument to `pluck` actually takes the place of the SELECT clause in the generated query, you can accomplish this just by a) moving your `.select()` invocation to the end of the chain and b) changing it to a `.pluck()`. For example, the following works in a quick demo app:

```
irb> User.group("name").order("SUM(age) DESC").pluck("name, SUM(age)")
   (1.0ms)  SELECT name, SUM(age) FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."name"  ORDER BY SUM(age) DESC
=> [["rob2", 13], ["rob4", 5], ["rob", 1]]
```

Any `joins` or `where` clauses should still work, too.